# How can I hide whmcs buttons?

Tags: hide, whmcs

Hi I hope someone can help on the client details page I need to hide the Email forwarding button and the DNS management button if the client has selected custom nameservers.   I just can't work it out son any help is much welcomed ..Here is the code that takes the input;

```
<form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=domaindetails">
<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="savens">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$domainid}">
<p><input type="radio" name="nschoice" value="default" id="nschoicedefault" onclick="usedefaultns()"{if $defaultns} checked{/if} /> <label for="nschoicedefault">{$LANG.nschoicedefault}</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="nschoice" value="custom" id="nschoicecustom" onclick="usecustomns()"{if !$defaultns} checked{/if} /> <label for="nschoicecustom">{$LANG.nschoicecustom}</label></p>
```

**And here is the code for the buttons;**

```
 {if $emailforwarding}
 <td><form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=domainemailforwarding">
    <input type="hidden" name="domainid" value="{$domainid}">
    <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="{$LANG.domainemailforwarding}" class="button">}
    </p>
    </form></td>
    {/if}
    {if $dnsmanagement}
    <td><form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=domaindns">
    <input type="hidden" name="domainid" value="{$domainid}">
    <p align="center">
    {<input type="submit" value="{$LANG.domaindnsmanagement}" class="button">}
    </p>
    </form></td>
    {/if}
```

Comment: Add tags for programming languages and frameworks used.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing a helper function and calling it at the top of the tpl file
and passing the domain id to it.

You can then use the WHMCS internal API function [Domain Nameservers](http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Domain_Nameservers) to get the domains nameservers then compare them against the default nameservers in the tblconfiguration in the WHMCS database.

Something like this

```
{php}
  // include our helper php file
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/Helper.php');

  //get domain id from our template variables 
  $domainid = $this->get_template_vars('domainid');

  //call to our helper function passing the domain ID
  $hasCustomeNameServers = Helper::hasCustomNameServers($domainid);

  //Once we've compared the nameservers agains the default ones we write
  //our binary check to the template
  if($hasCustomeNameServers >0){
  $this->assign('hasCustomeNameServers',true);}
{/php}
```

Then in side our Helper.php we have something like the following

```
<?php

 class Helper {
   public static function hasCustomNameServers($domainid) {

      $isCustom = 0;

     //Interal API call to get the domains nameservers
     $command = "domaingetnameservers";
     $adminuser = "admin";
     $values["domainid"] = $domainid;

     $results = localAPI($command,$values,$adminuser); 

     //get default nameservers
     $defautName1 ='';
     $sql = mysql_query('SELECT value FROM tblconfiguration '.
            ' WHERE setting = "DefaultNameserver1"');
     if ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {  
     $defautName1 = $res["value"];}

     $defautName2 ='';
     $sql = mysql_query('SELECT value FROM tblconfiguration '.
            ' WHERE setting = "DefaultNameserver2"');
     if ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {  
     $defautName2 = $res["value"];}

     //compare results
     foreach ($results as &$value) {
          if($value == $defautName1 || $value == $defautName2){
            $isCustom++;
          } 
     }

    return $isCustom;   

   }
 }
```

Now it's simply a matter on the template to wrap the  {if $emailforwarding} and the {if $dnsmanagement} blocks around our check {if !hasCustomeNameServers}

I hope this helps you in the right direction this is by no means a comprehensive answer but is a guide towards the approach I think you should take in implementing your solution.

Comment: Brilliant Stuff, Thank you.